# Can COM-object work with files beyond its folder?

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript, com

I've got a problem with accessing files from COM object:

I use 3rd party software which triggers events which can be handled by VB scripts. I use a script to handle one of these events. In the script I call my own C# COM object method to do some work. The method tries to read some files from the disk, but it fails because it can't find those files. I'm pretty sure the paths are correct.

It appears that the COM object has no permission to access files other than files within the same directory.

Is there a (proper) way to do this?

Comment: That sounds wrong.  Are you misusing relative paths?

Comment: A relative path is the opposite of an absolute path, like "c:\foo\bar\baz.txt".  "baz.txt" or "..\bar\baz.txt" or "\foo\bar\baz.txt" are relative paths.  Relative paths never work in a COM server, you cannot rely on the current drive and directory being set anywhere predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM processes run as whatever identity you've configured them to run as. Those identities have configurable permissions on the file system just like any other user or Windows security context. You can control which user your component runs as by opening the Component Services MMC snapin, drilling down to your component, right clicking it, selecting properties, and choosing the "Identity" tab. I've attached a picture.

[image: Component Services]